# Angularjs Directives Cleaner code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to apply this directive inside td cells, there are 6 columns and i want to apply only at the columns 1,2,3 and 5.

Is there a cleaner way to apply instead of applying raw html tags to these four cells ?

```
 <span ng-if="item.index === 2 
                              || item.index === 7
                              || item.index === 10
                              || item.index === 11">$ </span>
```

I end with a huge list of html code :

```
<td><span ng-if="item.index === 2 || item.index === 7 || item.index === 10 || item.index === 11">$ </span> {{item.label2 | number}}</td> <td><span ng-if="item.index === 2 || item.index === 7 || item.index === 10 || item.index === 11">$ </span> {{item.label3 | number}}</td> <td><span ng-if="item.index === 2 || item.index === 7 ......
```

Comment: You should move this logic to the controller, as a method, will make the view cleaner

Comment: will you please share more code please ?

Comment: please don't dump code into comments... update the actual question where the code can be formatted and readable and people don't have to sift through comments when reading the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree w/ the comment from `@Fals` that this logic can/should be in the controller but to make it more concise you can do something like this:

```
<span ng-if="[2,7,10,11].indexOf(item.index) >= 0">$ </span>
```

**UPDATE** per request of Ângelo Rigo:

To do this in the controller:

```
markup: //ctrlRef is reference to the controller (assuming controllerAs)
<span ng-if="ctrlRef.showItem(item)">$ </span>

// in the controller (ES5):
this.showItem = function(item){
  return [2,7,10,11].indexOf(item.index) >= 0;
}

// in the controller (ES6/TypeScript)
showItem(item) {
  return [2,7,10,11].indexOf(item.index) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brocco it is working, how would it written in a controller method ?